# ASP.NET iframe doesn't update, sometimes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

Below is my simplified .aspx file. Sometimes after clicking the 'update preview' button the iframe containing a modified .pdf file shows the up to date file. Sometimes, though, it takes several clicks until the iframe shows the up to date file.

Even if I redirect to the file directly in a new window, the .pdf file is still not up to date! (On my server's disk it is, though)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="pdfwebform.WebForm1" %>

<script runat="server">
void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf");
}

void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string answer = call_pdf(make_new, retails_array, restypes_array, selected_kids, brands_array);
    if (answer != "failed")
    {
        label1.Text = "Done!";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "No models meet selected criteria.";
    }
}

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Generate PDF Catalog</title>
        <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--
        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style1 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 105px;
            }
            .auto-style2 {
                width: 557px;
            }
        </style>
        -->
        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style1 {
                width: 84%;
            }
            .auto-style2 {
                text-align: left;
                width: 87px;
            }
            .auto-style3 {
                text-align: left;
                width: 486px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function appear() {
            document.getElementById("preview").style.display = 'block';
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function updatepreview() {
            if (document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML != "") {
                var iframe = document.getElementById("preview1");
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Please Wait...";
            }
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update_iframe() {
                var iframe = document.getElementById("preview1");
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function dot() {
            if (document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML == "d") {
                document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "nope";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "d";
            }
        }
        </script>

        <h1>Generate PDF Catalog</h1>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <!-- <embed id="preview" src="http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf" width="500px" height="500px" runat="server" /> -->
            <iframe id="preview1" src="http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf" width="500" height="500" runat="server"></iframe>
                <!-- Add to File Feature
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="new">Create New PDF</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="old">Add to Existing PDF</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                -->
                <table class="auto-style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">
                            <b>Retail:<br />
                            </b>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox5" runat="server" Height="45px" SelectionMode="multiple" Width="230px">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
                <b>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            Res Type:</b><br />
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox4" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="69px" Width="230px">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="OPTICAL">OPTICAL</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="KIDS">KIDS</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="SUN">SUN</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <b>Brand:</b><br />
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" Height="142px" Width="230px" SelectionMode="multiple" >
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="'AS'">ASPIRE</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'BCBG'">BCBGMAXAZRIA</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'CVO'">CLEARVISION</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'CH'">COLE HAAN</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'DD'">DILLI DALLI</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'DH'">DURAHINGE</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'ET'">ELLEN TRACY</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'IZOD'">IZOD</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'IZX'">IZOD PERFORMX</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'JMC'">JESSICA MCCLINTOCK</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'JC'">JUNCTION CITY</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'ME'">MARC ECKO</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'OP'">OCEAN PACIFIC</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="'PT'">PURITI</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />



                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" onchange="updatepreview()"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
            <!-- <embed id="preview" src="http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf" width="500px" height="500px" runat="server" /> -->
            <iframe id="preview1" src="http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf" width="500" height="500" runat="server"></iframe>
                            <br />

            <!-- <iframe id="frame" style="display:none"></iframe> -->
            <!-- <a href="javascript:download('http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf')">download</a> -->

                    &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">

                <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="updatepreview()"
                Text="Submit"></asp:Button>


                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style3">

                            *<font size="3">Hold Control/Command 
                            <br />
&nbsp;+ Click to select multiple</font>

                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style3">
                            <font size="3">
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Update Preview" OnClientClick="update_iframe()" />

                            </font>

                        </td>
                        <td class="align-right">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function download() {
                window.open("http://dev-db-02/pdf/catalog.pdf");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't put solved in the title. A question is considered 'solved' when the answer has an upvote or you've accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=help.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/pdf/catalog.pdf"));
    Response.End();
}
```

in your case you are redirecting the response with 301 to url witch return your file, the problem is that you are using 301 redirect and even if you are changing disk file browser will return cached 301 redirect (same file)

Comment: This allowed me to actually download the file, which is what I really wanted.